# Cross-platform space remaining on volume using python

Tags: python, windows, linux, macos, diskspace

I need a way to determine the space remaining on a disk volume using python on linux, Windows and OS X. I'm currently parsing the output of the various system calls (df, dir) to accomplish this - is there a better way?

Comment: See this recipe here:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577972-disk-usage/?in=user-4178764

Answer (score 79):

```
import ctypes
import os
import platform
import sys

def get_free_space_mb(dirname):
    """Return folder/drive free space (in megabytes)."""
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        free_bytes = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0)
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceExW(ctypes.c_wchar_p(dirname), None, None, ctypes.pointer(free_bytes))
        return free_bytes.value / 1024 / 1024
    else:
        st = os.statvfs(dirname)
        return st.f_bavail * st.f_frsize / 1024 / 1024
```

Note that you *must* pass a directory name for `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()` to work
(`statvfs()` works on both files and directories). You can get a directory name
from a file with `os.path.dirname()`.

Also see the documentation for [`os.statvfs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fstatvfs) and [`GetDiskFreeSpaceEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: `.f_bfree` is total number of free blocks in the file system. It should be multiplied by `.f_bsize` to get number of bytes.

Comment: At least on OS X Lion / Python 2.7 I noticed that multiplying by `.f_bsize` gives a much too large value as `f_bsize` is the *preferred* block size while `.f_frsize` is the *fundamental* block size and gives the correct value. On my linux test system both values are identical and thus `.f_frsize` should work all the time.

Comment: Works to get available disk on Android Phone, plugged via USB to a Windows system, running the script on Windows. Great.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian It depends on what you want. It is possible for Linux to reserve space for root. If you want to include this space, use f_bfree. If you want to get the number of blocks available to a user, then use f_bavail. Maybe someone can say if and how quotas are treated?

Comment: I have three *niggles* with the above: 1/ The docstring is wrong it returns space in Mbytes & 2/ I never like seeing more than one return statement, (too much time as a tester I guess), so would store the result in a returned value, 3/ Whole MB or decimal MB may make a difference to some people.

Comment: You can also check the platform via `sys.platform == 'win32'` sys is also available under `os`! So: `os.sys.platform == 'win32'`. Down to 2 imports! ;]

Comment: or `os.name == 'nt'`!

Answer (score 36):

Install [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) using `pip install psutil`. Then you can get the amount of free space in bytes using:

```python
import psutil
print(psutil.disk_usage(".").free)
```

Comment: Why this is not the best answer?

Comment: I think because psutil wasn't always available through pypi.

Comment: I agree this a great answer. I fixed the stale link to `psutil`. Since `disk_usage.free` typically returns a huge 64b integer, I suggest you also want to show people `disk_usage.percent`. `psutil.disk_usage(".").percent < 99.9` seems clearer to me...

Answer (score 30):

You could use the [wmi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/) module for windows and os.statvfs for unix

for window

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI ()
for d in c.Win32_LogicalDisk():
    print( d.Caption, d.FreeSpace, d.Size, d.DriveType)
```

for unix or linux

```
from os import statvfs

statvfs(path)
```

Comment: I can't believe how far I had to go down this question to find someone mentioning the WMI. All these crazy people using ctypes to call Windows C APIs directly when they could just use the WMI?

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes, you are right. We should use the right tool to do the right thing. Most of the common management tasks for window have already been wrapped with win api in wmi. We don't have to remake the wheel. :^D

Comment: Why not `psutil` handle it?

Comment: This is why I love stackoverflow.  I did not even know about the WMI module and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr yes, that's another good option for handle this task.

Comment: Well, if you want to support *vanilla* oldschool python 2.7: You need to do these things. The less external dependencies the better. `ctypes` is built-in! 

Answer (score 20):

## If you're running python3:

Using `shutil.disk_usage()`with `os.path.realpath('/')` name-regularization works:

```
from os import path
from shutil import disk_usage

print([i / 1000000 for i in disk_usage(path.realpath('/'))])
```

Or

```
total_bytes, used_bytes, free_bytes = disk_usage(path.realpath('D:\\Users\\phannypack'))

print(total_bytes / 1000000) # for Mb
print(used_bytes / 1000000)
print(free_bytes / 1000000)
```

giving you the total, used, & free space in MB.

Comment: Not sure how this isn't the selected answer. Doesn't require using `ctypes` which can be a hassle going through MSDN docs and ensuring types are coerced correctly.

Comment: IMHO this is the best way in this time and age.

Answer (score 10):

If you dont like to add another dependency you can for windows use ctypes to call the win32 function call directly.

```
import ctypes

free_bytes = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0)

ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceExW(ctypes.c_wchar_p(u'c:\\'), None, None, ctypes.pointer(free_bytes))

if free_bytes.value == 0:
   print 'dont panic'
```

Comment: Last few lines:  if free_bytes.value == 0:
    print('dont panic')
else:
    print(free_bytes.value)

Answer (score 7):

A good cross-platform way is using psutil: http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#disks
(Note that you'll need psutil 0.3.0 or above).

Comment: This would be the best answer, but unfortunately psutil is not installable via pip.

Comment: psutil is now available from pypi and most other sources including debian packages.

Answer (score 6):

From Python 3.3 you can use [shutil.disk_usage("/").free](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.disk_usage) from standard library for both Windows and UNIX :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [df](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=df) as a cross-platform way. It is a part of [GNU core utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). These are the core utilities which are expected to exist on every operating system. However, they are not installed on Windows by default (Here, [GetGnuWin32](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) comes in handy).

*df* is a command-line utility, therefore a wrapper required for scripting purposes.
For example:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

def free_volume(filename):
    """Find amount of disk space available to the current user (in bytes) 
       on the file system containing filename."""
    stats = Popen(["df", "-Pk", filename], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return int(stats.splitlines()[1].split()[3]) * 1024
```

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote. For example this answer may be useful to somebody. Anyway it is a good supplement for the other pupe-Pythonic solutions. If anybody doesn't like the answer is no reason to downvote it. As I understand, downvotes are for downright wrong answers. This one is not.

Comment: @ovgolovin Up vote this answer and It is good know an other way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The [os.statvfs()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html) function is a better way to get that information for Unix-like platforms (including OS X). The Python documentation says "Availability: Unix" but it's worth checking whether it works on Windows too in your build of Python (ie. the docs might not be up to date).

Otherwise, you can use the [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) library to directly call the [GetDiskFreeSpaceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364937(VS.85).aspx) function.

Comment: os.statvfs() doesn't work on Windows (Python 2.5.2 -- current production version).

Answer (score 1):

Below code returns correct value on windows

```
import win32file    

def get_free_space(dirname):
    secsPerClus, bytesPerSec, nFreeClus, totClus = win32file.GetDiskFreeSpace(dirname)
    return secsPerClus * bytesPerSec * nFreeClus
```

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know of any cross-platform way to achieve this, but maybe a good workaround for you would be to write a wrapper class that checks the operating system and uses the best method for each.

For Windows, there's the [GetDiskFreeSpaceEx](http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/docs/ActivePython/2.2/PyWin32/win32api__GetDiskFreeSpaceEx_meth.html) method in the win32 extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Most previous answers are correct, I'm using Python 3.10 and shutil.
My use case was Windows and C drive only ( but you should be able to extend this for you Linux and Mac as well (here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html))

Here is the example for Windows:

```
import shutil

total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage("C:/")

print("Total: %d GiB" % (total // (2**30)))
print("Used: %d GiB" % (used // (2**30)))
print("Free: %d GiB" % (free // (2**30)))
```