# How to get disk space total, used and free using Python 2.7 without PSUtil

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

Is there a way I get can the following disk statistics in Python without using PSUtil?

- Total disk space
- Used disk space
- Free disk space

All the examples I have found seem to use PSUtil which I am unable to use for this application.

My device is a Raspberry PI with a single SD card. I would like to get the total size of the storage, how much has been used and how much is remaining.

Please note I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check out this

```
import os
from collections import namedtuple

_ntuple_diskusage = namedtuple('usage', 'total used free')

def disk_usage(path):
    """Return disk usage statistics about the given path.

    Returned valus is a named tuple with attributes 'total', 'used' and
    'free', which are the amount of total, used and free space, in bytes.
    """
    st = os.statvfs(path)
    free = st.f_bavail * st.f_frsize
    total = st.f_blocks * st.f_frsize
    used = (st.f_blocks - st.f_bfree) * st.f_frsize
    return _ntuple_diskusage(total, used, free)
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7285483/2825570)

Comment: I think this is only Python3? I will modify my question to say I need Python 2.7. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `os.statvfs` function.