# Replacement for python statvfs?

Tags: python

The [python statvfs module](http://docs.python.org/library/statvfs.html) was marked as deprecated since python 2.6 and it's now removed since python 3.0. I haven't been able to figure out what apps are supposed to use if they want to get information about a disk, specifically how to check the capacity and free space of a given path. Anybody have any idea? This is on os x, if that makes a difference, although being cross platform would be a plus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that only the module that contains the constants for sequential access is being deprecated.

Doing

```
x = os.statvfs('/')
x.f_favail
```

will still work.

Sidenote: according to the docs, this function is only available on unix based platforms. So OSX and linux variants are fine, as is freeBSD and others, but windows won't be.

Comment: It seems Android also doesn't support os.statvfs()

Comment: `os.statvfs` was **removed in python3**. It was deprecated since python 2.6, see [python statvfs doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/statvfs.html).

Comment: @FranklinPiat to clarify, the `statvfs` module is deprecated, but in the `os` module, the `os.statvfs()` function is [still valid for Unix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.statvfs). Deprecated: `os.statvfs('/')[statvfs.F_FAVAIL]` Valid: `os.statvfs('/').f_favail`. But you do need [something else for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2372171/673991).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, it's [os.fstatvfs(fd)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=fstatvfs#os.fstatvfs)

> As of Python 3.3, this is equivalent to os.statvfs(fd). Availability:
>   Unix.

Comment: Does it have those constants that were exposed by statvfs.F_BLOCKS, statvfs.F_BSIZE?