# Batch script to check for disk space

Tags: batch-file

i need your help in putting together a batch script to monitor disk space on the logical drives and email if any of the drive crosses the threshold set.

I am unable to iterate and perform the calculations for each of the drives. How can i do it using the for loop and wmic or is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Which platform are you using?  Powershell + wmi could do this on windows.

Comment: I'm sure this could be done in batch, but I believe it would be more appropriate to use perfmon.exe. I've never used it, but I think this is the type of thing it is designed to do. Perhaps this would be a good question for the Super User (www.superuser.com) site instead.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you on your way, but then you'd have to parse the string... which is a bit complicated for the command line.

```
C:\>dir | find "bytes free"
           9 Dir(s)  21,954,252,800 bytes free
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you married to wmic? If not, you could take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2372171/1033808… which uses Python. To iterate over each of the drives, something like:

```
drive_list = ["c:","d:","e:"]
for drive in drive_list:
  free_space = get_free_space(drive)
  if free_space > threshold:
    send_mail("Drive %s crossed the threshold" % drive)
```

should do the trick. The send_mail function takes the body of the mail as input argument, see [this python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html) for sending an email.