# Python: script to clean windows disk after % usage

Tags: python, windows, disk

I created a python script for cleaning old files on a windows disk. Now I want to improve that script and check if I went over a predefined disk usage and then delete files ... how I can do it? Here's my code:

```
import os, time

path = r"f:\backup"
now = time.time()
for f in os.listdir(path):
    if os.stat(f).st_mtime < now - 180 * 86400:
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
```

I need it because I've configured a backup of my computer on external disk and sometimes it can't do the backup because disk is full.

Comment: What behavior are you looking for when disk space is exceeded? What will you remove in that case?

Comment: BTW, it would likely be a little faster to reverse the order of your `if` tests.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out this answer:

[Cross-platform space remaining on volume using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658/cross-platform-space-remaining-on-volume-using-python)

The nt implementation of the os module does not include the statvfs attribute, so you'd need to recreate that functionality using c_types.