# Python command to check the disk space on UNIX servers

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing a script which checks space on UNIX servers. But I am unable to find the right command. I used the following but it gives me same percentage for all paths.

`st = os.statvfs("/dev/hd3")`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260116/find-size-and-free-space-of-the-filesystem-containing-a-given-file

Comment: Try search for it. There's plenty of duplicates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658/cross-platform-space-remaining-on-volume-using-python/2372171#2372171

Answer (score 1):

You give it the mount point, not the device name.

So, instead of e.g.

```
st = os.statvfs("/dev/hd3")
```

you do

```
st = os.statvfs("/boot")
```